# Sending HTML to a printer in an SQL stored procedure

Tags: html, sql-server, stored-procedures, printing

I have a stored procedure that generates and sends HTML emails to customers using sp_send_dbmail.  I've gotten a request to print copies of the ones where I do not have an e-mail address on file, so they can mail them.  My kludge is to substitute in an email address for a mailbox on my exchange server that is set to forward the message to the Faxport of a copier in the MailRoom.  It works, but is extremely cumbersome, and subject to all kinds of delays due to the Fax-transmission.

It seems that since my SQL server is on the domain,  I should be able to route output directly to any printer installed on it from the Stored Procedure, but I have not been able to find any way to send HTML to a printer from a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Maybe some sort of C# extension?

Comment: Do you have SSRS set up?  This sounds like an excellent use for that.  Alternatively, is it possible to set up an account on the Exchange server that simply prints all email to a designated printer?

Comment: SSIS allows you to write to a text file. You can then print the file.

Comment: Ann, I do not have SSRS setup,  I'll have to look at that.  I tried having the Exchange account print automatically, but it seems that that becomes a client side rule, were, I'd need a computer logged in with Outlook open all the time for these to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures are great for manipulating data, but they are very limited when it comes to interacting with system resources outside the database. Even writing to a file can be awkward, never mind printing.

I think you should reconsider your design and develop an external script or program to do this, perhaps implemented as a Windows service. This program can call the stored procedure to get the HTML, then either email it or print it as appropriate.

A further enhancement would be to get only the data from the stored procedure and let the program format it as HTML or in any other format, probably using some sort of templating library and/or XSLT. That can be a very useful approach if you need to support multiple output formats ("important customer X wants the output to look a little different"), have different formatting based on business rules ("we need to add this disclaimer, but only for export orders") or provide output in multiple languages.

Comment: Pondlife, I understand where you are coming from.  My issue is this process was developed to send e-mails to customers, and we specifically asked it it would be necessary to print ones that did not have e-mails, and were told no.  Now its a requirement, and we are trying to not re-invent the wheel, and not have to maintain 2 copies of the e-mail template, as it changes frequently... That being said,  we'll take a step back and look at whether we can/should move the printing and e-mailing out of the procedure.

Comment: If the email format changes frequently then you need to focus on finding a solution that makes it easy to implement those changes. I would separate the data (stored procedure) from the formatting (external script) and find a good templating toolset that allows you to create and manage templates efficiently.